# JS Function for Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I would appreciate some help with this form I'm working on. The form itself came out really well; however the validation lets anything pass through.
When I intentionally violate every condition in the validation function separately (or together, in case I mixed up "true" and "false" on my returns, which it doesn't appear I did), absolutely nothing happens, when I should be getting an alert and the form should be blocked from submitting.

UPDATE: My first problem has been solved and I updated accordingly, leaving a comment at the area that ruined the script. I would still appreciate ways to shorten the script. In addition, I have a new problem. I am trying to use regEx to prevent users from entering non-alphabetic and non-whitespace characters; however, my code is ignoring the phrase `Jas@n X`, which also draws my attention to the fact that I also need more code to prevent people from entering their initials (whether first, last, or both). It feels like the problem is with the `.test(name)`.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
   function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["Involved"]["name"].value;
    if (!x) { //Here I now want to eliminate the possibility of ints or special characters. Preferably I have alternate error messages when a special/int is entered
     alert("Please enter your full name");
     return false;
    }
    if (/[^a-zA-Z\s:]+/.test(name)) {
     alert("Please refrain from using non-alphabetical characters.");
     return false;
    }
    if (!/[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+/.test(name)) {
     alert("Please enter a real name.")
     return false;
    }
    if (x.split(" ").length < 2) { // I misplaced parentheses here, making it "else if ((x.split " ".length < 2)) {", which broke the script. 
     alert("Please enter your first name as well as your last name.");
     return false;
    }
    var y = document.forms["Involved"]["email"].value;
    if (!y) {
     alert("Please enter an email address.");
     return false;
    }
    var atpos = y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = y.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length) {
     alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
     return false;
    }
    var z = document.forms["Involved"]["help"].value;
    if (!z) {
     alert("Please let us know how you intend to help.");
     return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="Involved" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
   Name: <br><input type="text" name="name" title="Your full name" style="color:#888" placeholder="Enter full name"/>
   <br><br>
   Email: <br><input type="text" name="email" title="Your email address" style="color:#888" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
   <br><br>
   How you can help: <br><textarea cols="18" rows="3" name="help" title="Service you want to provide" style="color:#888" placeholder="Please let us know of any ways you may be of assistance"></textarea>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id=submitbox"/>
  </form>
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: use `placeholder` instead `value`.
http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: @meni181818 Thank you! I will take care of it. A few things: 1) Does it have any non-aesthetic effect on the code, or does it just make it easier to read/reference? 2) Adding on to [1], does doing this mean that I can take out the parts of my code that say `if (varname) == "What I put as a prompt in the field at the bottom"`? 3) A variant of [2]; will this render the value as `null` and fall under the, simpler, condition `if (varname)`?

Comment: the Answer for all the questions is: `placeholder` It is not Affects the `value`. the value Will stay `""`. so you dont have to check if the value == to the Default (`placeholder`)

Comment: @meni181818 Thank you for everything! Have a good rest of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have javascript error in this line, you can see it if you open developer tools in your browser:

```
else if ((x.split " ".length < 2)) {
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

there is wrong parentheses placement, should be

```
else if (x.split(" ").length < 2) {
```

Additional edits that you can do with your code:

Do not include jQuery library if you really don't need it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

You shouldn't use javascript for filling default input values, there is nice HTML5 attribute `placeholder`, so you can use it and change your inputs from this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" title="Your full name" style="color:#888" value="Enter full name" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
```

to simply this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" title="Your full name" placeholder="Enter full name"/>
```

For javascript code in general: if you do `return` when `if` statement is true, you can continue writing your `else` code without wrapping it in `else` statement, for example:

```
function check() {
    var a = 1;

    if (a != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (a != 3) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

can be changed to more readable:

```
function check() {
    var a = 1;

    if (a != 2) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a != 3) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly--thanks a lot! It's amazing what a pair of parentheses can do.

Is there any way to shrink my code further, or is that pretty much it?

Comment: So is a `return true` line even necessary? If not, should I keep it in just to be safe (like a `* {misc styling}` in HTML) or just chuck it?

Comment: Also, does the `placeholder` element also work for mobile browsers?

Comment: In your case `return true` is not necessary, as it doesn't change behaviour of form submission, but you can leave it to clarify result of function execution. `placeholder` is supported by modern mobile browsers, details can be found here: http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here (it's probably a typo). You are missing braces after split here:

```
else if ((x.split " ".length < 2))
```

instead you shoud write  `x.split(" ")`.
You also don't need to use double braces here (it doesn't prevent code from working though).

The other advice: you can use just `if (varName)` instead of `if (varName == null || varName == "" )` here.

Also, maybe it is excessive, but since you say you are new to js: it is always helpful to look in browser console if something doesn't work as expected. There was an exception with a number of line where it occured, and thi is how I found the error.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I have not been using developer tools--so that wasn't excessive at all. I will download a set as soon as I can. So `if (varname)` means "if varname has no value?" Also, does it work with other conditions, such as `if (varname) || varname=="lorum ipsum"`?

Comment: @Bucephalus You are welocme! `if (varname || varname=="lorum ipsum")` will be correct, as the whole condition of the if-statement should be in braces. And good news: you don't need to download developer tools, they are built-in in chrome and FF. Just press F12

Comment: I forgot one thing. `if (varname)` will work if varname evaluates to fasle. For example, undefined, empty string, NAN.
You can look up what converts to false [here](http://es5.github.io/x9.html#x9.2)

Comment: That makes sense; thanks. Your "NaN" reminded me: is there a test I can add that proves they're not inputting numbers?

Comment: @Bucephalus Yes, you can use [regExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for that. To check if the string includes numbers or maybe some other symbols you don't wont in it (such as special symbols in name :))

Comment: I checked out your link, but am having a bit of trouble understanding how to use regExp. Let's say I wanted someone's name. I would first check `if (name)`. I would then, before my `split`, use regExp. I know that `\d` and `\W` would be what I checked for, but how would I check for both of them at the same time without false positives/negatives?

Comment: I would use, for example, `if (/[^a-zA-Z\s:]+/.test(name))`. But of course there are many ways how you can do it :)
BTW, i found an innatentive mistake in what I wrote yesterday. `If (varname)` will work if varname evaluates to true for sure (but I guess you understood what I meant). For opposite `if (!varname)` is used.

Comment: Thanks! Can you quickly provide an overview of how that code works? Specifically: I don't understand the colon in front of the `s` or the entire existence of the second slash `/.test(name)`. Again, I really want to thank you for your patience; I know you're not obligated to answer my questions.

Comment: Second `/` is just because you always place the regular expression in js  between two `/`. And about ':' - I don't know where I got it from, it means your code will be valid with symbol ':', but it's not what you need actually. So it's a reason that you don't have to thank me much because I am not as accurate as I have to be :)

Comment: I figured out RegEx and everything works perfectly now. Again, thanks for everything!